# Match SiteScope Log file path

Tags: regex, sitescope

I'm trying to monitor a log file using sitescope. The file is came from the ReportServer and has format of

**ReportServerService__02_18_2015_00_00_01.log**

I can get the month, day and year but when I trying to inject a regex to match the succeeding text, It cannot read the file. If I hard coded the succeeding text it works.

Below is the Log file path text I used. but it can't read the file.

```
 s/\\server\LogFiles\ReportServerService__$0month$_$0day$_$year$_([0-
 9][0-9])_([0-9][0-9])_([0-9][0-9]).log/
```

Comment: Sitescope HP monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
s/\\\\server\\LogFiles\\ReportServerService__$0month$_$0day$_$year$_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.log/
```